# Maximally symmetric space is completely determined by its constant scalar curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, symmetry

We define a maximally symmetric space as a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ that around each point has the maximum number of $n(n+1)/2$ linearly independent infinitesimal isometries, $n=\dim M$. Equivalently, there exist $n(n+1)/2$ linearly independent Killing vector fields. For such a space one can show that the Riemann curvature tensor can be written as

$$R_{ijkl} = \frac{S}{n(n-1)}(g_{ik}g_{jl} - g_{il}g_{jk}),$$

where $S$ is the scalar curvature, which must be *constant*.

Now a lot of (mainly physics) references tell me that this formula implies that two maximally symmetric Riemannian manifolds having the same scalar curvature $S$ must be locally isometric. I haven't been able to find a single proof of the statement, however, even after consulting maybe dozens of references.

So assuming the statement is true and does not tacitly need more additional assumptions, how would one prove this? References would be most appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you know that both manifolds have the same constant sectional curvature, it follows by using the Jacobi equation to calculate the form of the metric in geodesic normal coordinates. You can find a proof in my book *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds* (2nd ed.), Corollary 10.15.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed. I figured the proof would have something to do with sectional curvature and that it is not as trivial as a lot of my references make it seem. Quick question: so maximal symmetry implies constant sectional curvature; is the converse true as well? Does constant sectional curvature imply that the space is maximally symmetric?

Comment: @Sjorszini: As long as you define "maximally symmetric" the way you did -- by the existence of the maximum number of independent Killing fields in a neighborhood of each point, and not by the existence of a global isometry group of that dimension -- then yes. The proof is almost immediate from the previous result: constant sectional curvature implies the metric is locally isometric to the appropriate Euclidean, spherical, or hyperbolic space form, and you can use that local isometry to transport the Killing fields from the model space.

Comment: Ah you're right of course, thanks for pointing it out.